# Using SVD and positive definite to prove a property

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been trying really hard to prove a property, but I just cannot

For $A = U\Sigma V^T$ , such that $U^TU=I=UU^T$ and $V^TV=I=VV^T$ and the column vectors of $U$ and $V$ are orthonormal, and the standard SVD properties hold

$Av_i = s_iu_i$ and $A^Tu_i = s_iv_i$ then we hant to show the following property

$\sum_i^n  \frac{s_i}{s_i^2 + a} (u_id)v_i = (A^TA+aI)^{-1}A^Td$ is true for some vector $d$. What I have tried so far was work backwards and start with 
$$(A^TA+aI)^{-1}A^Td$$
Then aim to decompose A, which avails 
$$(V\Sigma^2V^T+aI)^{-1}*V\Sigma(U^Td)$$

But I am now confused how do I deal with that inverse. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S,T$ are invertible matrices, we have $(ST)^{-1}=T^{-1}S^{-1}$.

In our case, we have $V^{-1}=V^T$ and vice versa.

Also, since $A$ is p.d. and $a>0$ we have that $(V\Sigma^2V^T + aI)$ us invertible and $$(V\Sigma^2V^T + aI)^{-1}=(V\Sigma^2V^T + aVV^T)^{-1}=(V^T)^{-1}(\Sigma^2 + aI)^{-1}V^{-1}=V(\Sigma^2 + aI)^{-1}V^T.$$

Note that since both $\Sigma$ and $aI$ are diagonal matrices, the matrix $(\Sigma^2 + aI)^{-1}$ is also a diagonal matrix with $\frac{1}{s_i^2 + a}$ on its diagonal.